# Python - How to set conditions for key bindings

Tags: python, tkinter, conditional-statements

recently I've found this piece of code here ([How to draw a line following your mouse coordinates with tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47996285/how-to-draw-a-line-following-your-mouse-coordinates-with-tkinter)):

```
import tkinter as tk

def draw(event):
    x, y = event.x, event.y
    if canvas.old_coords:
        x1, y1 = canvas.old_coords
        canvas.create_line(x, y, x1, y1)
    canvas.old_coords = x, y

def draw_line(event):

    if str(event.type) == 'ButtonPress':
        canvas.old_coords = event.x, event.y

    elif str(event.type) == 'ButtonRelease':
        x, y = event.x, event.y
        x1, y1 = canvas.old_coords
        canvas.create_line(x, y, x1, y1)

def reset_coords(event):
    canvas.old_coords = None

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=400, height=400)
canvas.pack()
canvas.old_coords = None

root.bind('<ButtonPress-1>', draw_line)
root.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', draw_line)

#root.bind('<B1-Motion>', draw)
#root.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', reset_coords)

root.mainloop()
```

and I'm really curious how to make those functions working accordingly to e.g. selected option. Let's say, I'd want select when draw free-hand and when draw lines.
I've tried using one integer for comparison and then define conditions for binds, like this:

```
if c==1:
    root.bind('<ButtonPress-1>', draw_line)
    root.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', draw_line)
elif c==2:
    root.bind('<B1-Motion>', draw)
    root.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', reset_coords)
```

but it doesn't seem to work. Have You got any ideas how to make conditions for binding?

Comment: You must do the binding for the function to be called. Try to create a callback to a new draw_general function on which to check for `c`'s value and to call the matching function.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't fully understand... :D Could You explain it, please?

Comment: Create a new function and call it `draw_general`. Then instead of doing root.bind on `draw_line` do it on `draw_general`. Then in this function do a check for `c`'s value. If it is 1 call `draw_line` and if it is 2 call `draw`. The problem is that binding happens once and not after each triggering, so you should bind once and then handle your cases in the callback (in my example `draw_general`. Hope this helps

Comment: What key/action should I bind the draw_general function to? And where do I define before-used binds - press and release?

Comment: I have figured it out, thanks for help

Comment: Please create an answer with the solution you figured out so that people can later use this question for their own problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as stated at the comments section, I created a function which merged operations of two original functions and then I binded all used keysyms to new function

Comment: Thanks! Can you put your working code with the answer?