# How to draw slick lines using PIL and Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I'm making a Pixel Art package with Pillow (PIL) and Tkinter. So far, I have set up a code that draws a continuous line on mouse motion path. However, the line isn't slick.

I'm tried drawing five pixels x-2, x-1, x, x+1, x+2 yet still, the line isnt't slick.

import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image

```
def tinker(img, pos, color):
   pixels = img.load()
    x = pos[0]
    y = pos[1]

if (x > 3 and y > 3) and (x < 253 and y < 253):
    pixels[x-2, y] = color
    pixels[x - 1, y] = color
    pixels[x , y] = color
    pixels[x + 1, y] = color
    pixels[x + 2, y] = color
elif x < 3 and y < 3:
    x = 3
    y = 3
elif x > 253 and y > 253:
    x = 253
    y = 253


img.save("image.png")


 root = tk.Tk()

 img = Image.new("RGB", (256, 256), color="white")
 img.save("image.png")
 openimg = tk.PhotoImage(file="image.png")
 panel = tk.Label(root, image=openimg)
 panel.pack(side="bottom", fill="both", expand="yes")


def callback(e):
    x, y = e.x, e.y
    print(f"({x}, {y})")
    tinker(img, pos=(x, y), color=(0, 0, 0))
    img2 = tk.PhotoImage(file="image.png")
    panel.configure(image=img2)
    panel.image = img2


root.bind("<B1-Motion>", callback)
root.mainloop()
```

I expected slick lines, a la Photoshop, GIMP and Paint.net.

Comment: Possible duplicate [how-to-draw-a-line-following-your-mouse-coordinates-with-tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47996285/how-to-draw-a-line-following-your-mouse-coordinates-with-tkinter)

Comment: Please fix your indentation, couldnt edit since there were not enough changes.